# Не отображаются ошибка в коде в VS Code

Tags: golang, visual-studio-code

Раньше когда писал **код с ошибкой был подчеркивание с красный линий в VS Code**.Вроде ничего не менял в настройках,но сейчас даже явную ошибку не подсказывает.В гугле не могу найти как исправить

Как пример в цикле **for o, w := range data** переманная **o** должна подчеркиваться (в Go если переменная не используется то ее не должна быть)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Просто надо было удалить расширение **Rich Go language support for Visual Studio Code** и перезаустить VS Code и переустановить расширение.